# 2D Canvas in Browser

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, 2d, openlaszlo

I'm looking for a framework or library to use the browser as a 2D "drawing" tool.

Acctually drawing is not the right word. It should be a adding, removing and moving around of 2D objects and images on a canvas. The objects should be graphically connectable. So - kind a visio in a browser

I guess it's a bit to much for a javascript library like dojo or prototype but what about a flash framework like flex or openlaszolo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers now support the `<canvas>` tag in HTML5, which does pretty much what you're asking for. You can draw directly onto it using Javascript. Also in most modern browsers is support for the SVG graphic format, which again can be manipulated via Javascript to do some very funky effects. The difference between canvas and SVG is that canvas is for bitmap graphics and SVG is vectors. But both are good for 2D drawing.

If you need a library or framework on top of that, you could try something like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which is a good JS library for drawing vector graphics. It even supports older versions of Explorer, which is a bonus. (if SVG isn't available it falls back to VML).

Answer (score 1):

[iLog Exlixir](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/elixir-enterprise/about/?S_CMP=rnav) offers some graphing components which would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLaszlo can definitely do this. Here is a link to an OpenLaszlo application that is an online alternative to Visio:

http://www.gliffy.com/

I also have personally developed and maintained an OpenLaszlo video editing application over the past 6 years that allows you to drag images and videos to different positions and layers similar to what you describe, you can try it here if you want:

http://www.sarolta.tv/web/sarolta-tools/template-editor.html